Mystery crystals exuded from eastern redcedar heartwood
A dead eastern redcedar (Juniperus virginiana) was recently cut and the wood saved for later woodworking. From the chainsawn face, a rime of acicular radii appeared only on the colored heartwood over the course of a month or so. The minute crystals are tasteless and have a rough melting point of 72-75°C. What could be the identity of this substance?

An uneducated guess would be a certain oxalate (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druse_(botany)).

BTW, tasting oxalates might not be a good idea. (Though rhubarb is eaten.)

Biology SE might be a better home for this

@andselisk I don't believe any oxalate would have a melting point that low.

Maybe this one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedrene
